# Правильная передача объектов jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть глобальный массив:

`var clubs = new Array();`

Есть функция которая принимает данные и формирует объект:

```
function Club(data) {
  this.name = data.name;
  this.key = data.key;
  this.code = data.code;
}
```

Есть функция отправляющая get-запрос и получающая JSON:

```
function GetLiguesToRegards(element) {
  namesClass = $(element).attr("class").split(' ');
  $.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/' + namesClass[1] + '/' + namesClass[0] + '.1.clubs.json', function (text, status) {
    clubData = JSON.parse(text);
    //clubs = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < clubData.clubs.length; i++) {
        var currentClub = new Club(clubData.clubs[i]);
        clubs.push(clubData.clubs[i]);
    }
    //console.log(clubs);
  });
}
```

так вот, объекты, которые я ложу в массив (которые я сформировал в функции `GetLiguesToRegards`) почему-то не попадают в него.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: в дополнение к дубликату: в массив складываются не созданные объекты `currentClub`, а те же самые `clubData.clubs[i]`, которые передавались в конструктор